# C# - UDP SocketException - Conflict between applications

Tags: c#, asp.net, udp

I'm building a dashboard like website for a formula 1 game.
I followed this [guide](http://forums.codemasters.com/discussion/46726/d-box-and-udp-telemetry-information). (Section : Enabling the UDP Telemetry Output)

Basically, the game sends packets on 127.0.0.1:20777 using UDP, and I'm trying to receive these packets in my app.

My problem is that there seems to be some sort of conflict between the game and my app when I try to receive the packets. For instance, if I compile the app when the game is not running, it compiles just fine, but of course, I do not receive any data.

Once the game is started, I cannot compile, and get a SocketException that says "Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted".

I tried the following :

`UdpClient client = new UdpClient(20777);`

and

`UdpClient client = new UdpClient();
IpEndPoint ip = new IpEndPoint(IpAdress.Any, 20777);
client.Connect(ip);`

The first solution throws "Only one usage...", and the second solution throws "The requested address is not valid in its context". I am very new to UDP, so I don't really know what am I doing wrong or how to fix it.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i believe you should be trying to listen on the port 20777 rather than trying to connect.

May be something like this:

```
var client = new UdpClient();
IPEndPoint ep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 20777 ); // endpoint where server is listening
client.Connect(ep);

// then receive data
var receivedData = client.Receive(ref ep);

Console.Write("receive data from " + ep.ToString());

Console.Read();
```

Comment: I'll give it a shot when I get home tonight, thanks !